# Replace HealthCheckService in WebApplicationFactory for integration testing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, health-check

I am writing integration tests for my health check endpoint and I have replaced the `DbContext` in `WebApplicationFactory` using a test database as follows:

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
  services
    .RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>() // Remove previously registered DbContext
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((sp, options) =>
    {
      options.UseNpgsql(_connection);
    });

// =====> How do I remove the previously registered health check service here
     services.AddHealthChecks().AddNpgSql(_connection.ConnectionString);
});
```

How do I go about removing the previously registered health check services and then register them again passing the connection string from the test database instead.

I tried `services.RemoveAll<HealthCheckService>()` but it didn't work. I get an error message `Duplicate health checks were registered with the name(s): npgsql (Parameter 'registrations')`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few hours, I finally found a solution. I added

```
services.Configure<HealthCheckServiceOptions>(options =>
{
  options.Registrations.Clear();
});
```

before

```
services.AddHealthChecks().AddNpgSql(_connection.ConnectionString);
```

and everything worked. :)